# How do I return a react component inline from a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to return a react component which just contains a bit of styled text (styling omitted for example) which I get add to my app further down the line.  Here is the snipped of code which returns the react component:

```
import React from 'react';
const getMessage = (): React.Component => {
    return <span>Test</span>;
};
```

However I get the following error:

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As it's telling you, what you've returned is an *element*, not a *component*.

Comment: Ok, how do I return a component?  I need to attach it as a child of a React component, and as far as I can tell, I can't attach an element?

Comment: Are you using `typescript`

Comment: Use `React.SFC` and `return () => <span>Test</span>`?

Comment: @IshanJoshi yes this is typescript.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that doesn't seem to work either; Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | null'

Comment: Note you need to return *a function returning the element*, that's what a functional component is. See https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

Comment: Do you want your function to return a React element or a React component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because the declared return type of your function is `React.Component` while the function itself returns a React Element or a `React.ReactElement`.